# Sort all Incomes monthly group by year added

Tags: php, mysql

Want to show all my expenses monthly and group yearly like the picture bellow [][2] and the code looks like this

```
SELECT 
    monthname(date_added) as monthname,
    year(date_added) as year,
    SUM(amount) as amounts 
    FROM incomes GROUP BY year ORDER BY monthname
```

2017
Jan $100
Feb $200
Jul $90 
Jun $300

---

2018

Jan $100
Feb $200
Jul $90 
Jun $300

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Tell us what does not work. Don't hesitate to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

seem  you need  order by date and month

```
    select t.year, t.monthname, t.amounts
    from(
         SELECT monthname(date_added) as monthname, 
                month(date_added) month, 
                year(date_added) as year,
                SUM(amount) as amounts 
                FROM incomes 
                GROUP BY year, month, monthname
    )
    ORDER BY t.year, t.month
```

or if you need two separated  result for this year and the previous year

for actual year  you could

```
select t.year, t.monthname, t.amounts
from(
     SELECT monthname(date_added) as monthname, 
            month(date_added) month, 
            year(date_added) as year,
            SUM(amount) as amounts 
            FROM incomes 
            where year(date_added) = year(curdate())
            GROUP BY year, month, monthname
)
ORDER BY t.year, t.month
```

and for the previous year you could

```
select t.year, t.monthname, t.amounts
from(
     SELECT monthname(date_added) as monthname, 
            month(date_added) month, 
            year(date_added) as year,
            SUM(amount) as amounts 
            FROM incomes 
            where year(date_added) = year(curdate()) -1 
            GROUP BY year, month, monthname
)
ORDER BY t.year, t.month
```

Comment: does it return array?

Comment: can you please tell me how I can show the data into table like the photo?

Comment: you have not photo  ... in your question

Comment: sorry I have not permission to upload photo, I edited the post added those list, i want the code should be like that

Comment: looking to your data seems you need  two different query  .. one for an year and one for previous year  ..

Comment: how i write those two queries